# how Ignore TS Errors TS2339: “property does not exist on value of type” with eslint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

My React js project failed and I got many times this error:

> The TS2339: property 'x' does not exist on value of type 'y'

my tsconfig.json file :

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"jsx": "react",
"target": "es6",
"module": "esnext",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"sourceMap": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"removeComments": false,
"noImplicitAny": false,
"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
"outDir": "target/classes/static/app",
"lib": ["es2015", "es2017", "dom"],
"types": ["webpack-env", "jest"],
"allowJs": true,
"checkJs": false,
"baseUrl": "./",
"paths": {
  "app/*": ["src/main/webapp/app/*"]
},
"importHelpers": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["src/main/webapp/app", "src/test/javascript/spec"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

How fix it?

Comment: Are you sure this is coming from eslint. This looks like a problem from the typescript compiler. Can you show the full output of an example please.

Comment: It is probably a typing mismatch between your component's state and/or props. Please post more code

Answer (score -4):

Maybe adding this rule to tsconfig will help

```
"noImplicitAnyForClassMembers": false
```

Comment: This is not a valid property of compilerOptions